# PHP not grabbing form information

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm relatively new to PHP and I'm having trouble getting my PHP to take my form data and submit it in an email. The email sends to me with the plain text I have in it but all the form data isn't there. Does anybody have any ideas of what's wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="box3" class="clearfix">
        <form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            <div id="greyContainer" class="clearfix">
            <p id="text5">
            Contact Us
            </p>
            <p id="text6">
            Feel free to contact us and leave a message if you have any general questions&#x21;
            </p>

            <label id="formgroup">
                <p id="text7">
                Name&#x3a;
                </p>
                <input id="name" type="text" value="Full Name" name="name"></input>
            </label>
            <label id="formgroup1">
                <p id="text8">
                Number&#x3a;
                </p>
                <input id="phone_number" type="text" value="Phone Number" name="phone_number"></input>
            </label>
            <label id="formgroup2">
                <p id="text9">
                Email&#x3a;
                </p>
                <input id="email" type="text" value="Email Address" name="email"></input>
            </label>
            <label id="formgroup3">
                <p id="text10">
                Message&#x3a;
                </p>
                <textarea id="message_block" name="message_block" >Message or question...</textarea>
            </label>
            <p id="text11">
            <span id="textspan">AVA Roofing &amp; Siding<br />12 Arcade Ave.<br />Amherst, NY 14226<br />716.602.3947</span><br />&nbsp;
            </p>
            <img id="image1" src="img/envelope.png" class="image" />
            <a href="thank_you.html">
                <input id="input" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" ></input>
            </a>

            <div id="whiteLine" class="clearfix">
            </div>
    </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

 $to = "example@gmail.com" ; 
$from = $_POST['email'] ; 
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$headers = "From: $from"; 
$subject = "AVA Roofing Contact Form"; 
$message2 = $_POST['message_block'];
$number = $_POST['phone_number'];

$message = "A visitor has submitted the following requirements. \n\nName:         $name\n\nEmail: $email\n\nNumber: $number\n\nMessage: $message";

$headers = "From:" . $from;
$headers2 = "From:" . $to;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

$send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);  
if($send) 
{header( "Location: http://www.example.com/folder/thank_you.html" );} 
else 
{print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please notify                    webmaster@YourCompany.com"; }

?>
```

Comment: Include a `print_r($_POST)` at the top to verify what data the script is receiving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got the wrong encoding on your form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Since you're telling the browser to send it as text/plain, it will not be processed by PHP. For this simple form, you don't need to specify ANY encoding. Just accept the defaults.

If you insist on specifying an encoding, it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for standard forms, or `multipart/form-data` if you're doing file uploads.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you so much! There's so much more I need to learn about PHP but I'm glad you responded quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can send to other file like file.php and in this file the action you would have something like this:

```
   $recipiente = "your@email.com ";
   $asunto = "Formulario";
   $message ="name: ".$name."<br>";
   $message .="email: ".$email."<br>";
   $message .="coment: ".$coment."<br>";

   $message = stripslashes($message);

   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
   $headers .= "From: $email\r\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-to: $email\r\n";
   $headers .= "Cc: $email\r\n";

   mail($recipiente,$asunto,$message,$headers);
```